# Date format Issue in SQL Server or ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

When I run a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 CTP I get date `"2012-10-31 00:00:00.000"` with this format.

But when I am converting it using

```
Convert.ToString(drConversation["ConversationDate"])
```

in C#, I am getting `"10/31/2012 12:00:00 AM"`.

Where should be problem? In C# code or in SQL Server?

Comment: Those values are identical; what is the problem?

Comment: You can easily call `Convert.ToDateTime(drConversation["ConversationDate"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")` in C# and get the exact same format as SQL Server returns - so **what is the REAL problem** here?? I don't see any issue....

Comment: Data Masseur: When I am parsing string to Date time I have error. The error=> " DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar."

Comment: Marc_s : DateTimeParseExcect(Convert.ToString(drConversation["ConversationDate"])) In function : I am returning  DateTime.ParseExact(DateValue.Substring(0,10),DateExectParse, null); and My "DateExectParse" is format "dd/MM/yyyy".

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with it, The SQLServer use `24-hr format` while the output from *Convert class* outputs `12-hr format`.

Comment: then why  date format is change from"YYY-dd-mm" to "MM/dd/YYYY"?

Comment: because it is *by default*. do you want it to retain the format?

Comment: @chiragKhatsuriya you can use `Convert.ToDateTime(drConversation["ConversationDate"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")`

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is the same date but in a different [format](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx).

If you would like to see it in the same format as in the Sql Server you can use:

`DateTime.Parse(drConversation["ConversationDate"].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: Why would you convert to string, then to Date, then back to string?  `((Date) drConversation["ConversationDate"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")` should do it right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
DateTime mydate= Convert.ToDateTime(drConversation["ConversationDate"].ToString());
```